# How to speed up bindingHandler for jquery-ui Spinner

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I got this binding for a knockout spinner:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.spinner = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().spinnerOptions || {};


        $(element).spinner(options);

        //handle the field changing
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "spinchange", function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($(element).spinner("value"));
        });

        //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).spinner("destroy");
        });

    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            current = $(element).spinner("value");

        if (value !== current) {
            $(element).spinner("value", value);
        }
    }
};
```

It works no problem, but when I add a lot of these to a page I get performance issues.
On my page I have 44 spinners and that causes the view 2 seconds to load. Replacing the spinner with an  with a "value"-binding fix the performance problem but does´t look as great. 
Any suggestions how to speed up the bindingHandler to make it more efficient?

Comment: Can you please recreate the issue in a jsFiddle?

Comment: Too big and complex. I have tested it down to being the spinner.handler taking the time as mentioned above...

Comment: If it is too big and complex for you to recreate than how do you expect us to be able to?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your custom binding that is significantly slowing it down. Your binding is a perfect example of the simplest form of combining a jQuery UI plugin with Knockout. I have tons of bindings like these, with hundreds added to a page and no performance problems.

So what is the problem? We can't tell you, because the relevant code isn't there. The slowest part of this feature is probably the spinner itself, not the binding you created. To speed it up, you need to optimize the spinner plugin. I don't know if that is at all possible because there's nothing about this plugin mentioned in your post.

On a whole different note: displaying 44 spinners on a page probably isn't going to help the user experience. Maybe you should slow down on the spinner usage :p

Comment: Replacing the spinner with an with a pure "value"-binding fix the performance problem, so I guess it´s the spinner-handler somehow.